# Best way to store multiple (more than 100000) binary files in Django

Tags: django, filesystems

I need to operate on about 100000 small (5kb) sound files. I think to use FileField and save them on disk. But I am in doubt because there will be folder with 100000 files, I am sure that can seriously hit the perfomance. What can you advise?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there will be performance issue, because `FileField` will only store the file path of the file you have, thus retrieving a file takes O(1) time by following the path.